# Как вставить видео на страницу?

Tags: html, css

без звука, но с автоплеем

Как вставить видео на страницу?

например, для сафари есть проблема

Ignores the autoplay attribute by default, though autoplay behavior can be enabled by users

Comment: `<video autoplay muted ...` запускается без каких-либо проблем, в т.ч. в Safari (если не включен режим энергосбережения)

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/
Политика авто воспроизведения видео поменялась.

Вы можете попробовать добавить атрибут `muted`

А так же применить различные библиотеки, например как
https://codepen.io/sann/pen/aRJZQy